# VS2015 Publish Error: No executable found matching command "Runs"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I used the MVC6 Boilerplate template and have it all running well locally, however whenever I attempt the publish process (via the right-click on the project option) I get the following error;

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(149,5): Error : No executable found matching command "Runs"

I've googled that message with no luck.  This occurs no matter the publish mode (FTP, Web Deploy, etc).  I see that there are others getting an error on "Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(149,5)" but they don't seem directly related, or at least haven't offered me info that I could use to continue to trace down.

I assume it's just a config related problem, I just don't know enough about the internals of the deployment build process to track down where this command is attempting to be invoked.  Searching for "Runs" in the code also provides no results and must be in a non-searchable file or related .dll like "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

Any point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is specific to the MVC6 template.  I logged the issue there and will post the solution once it is determined [link]https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC-Boilerplate/Templates/blob/master/MVC%206.md

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the git solution for the MVC6 boilerplate and upon opening it gave me an about the missing .Net Core SDK.  Installing it resolved the issue;
[link] https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues.md#missing-sdk